# Is there any way to loop through uri segments in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering if there is a way to loop through all the uri segments in a URL...

/segment1/segment2/segment3/

Is it possible to loop through these with a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a segment specifically via `$this->uri->segment(n)` or iterate the segments like so:

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();

foreach ($segs as $segment) {
    echo $segment . '<br />';
}
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_string();
```

You can use `explode()` to cut it in peaces and put in an array. Then use `foreach` to loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about foreach, but you should be able to use a 'for'  with $this->uri->segment($id)
from within a controller.